# Eclipse fails to create JVM after defining --launcher.XXMaxPermSize in eclipse.ini

Tags: java, eclipse, memory, virtual-machine

I was using Eclipse and I got `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space` error. In Eclipse FAQ it says I should add these lines to eclipse.ini:

```
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
[xxx]m
```

where xxx is the memory size I want to use (I tried 256). But after I do this I get `Failed to create Java Virtual Machine` error on Eclipse startup. What should I do to get it working?

---

My eclipse.ini file *before* editing:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.100.v20110502
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Xms40m
-Xmx1024m
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to adjust your eclipse.ini to include the argument `-XX:MaxPermSize` + specify a specific JVM for Eclipse to run on by adding the **-vm** option just before the **-vmargs** option. Ex:

```
-vm
C:\Java\JDK\1.6\bin\javaw.exe (The exact path to javaw.exe)
-vmargs
-Xms40m
-Xmx1024m
```

**The -vm option and its value (the path) must be on separate lines.**

A complete example:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.100.v20110502
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm
C:\Java\JDK\1.6\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx768m
```

Comment: Well, now I got a fatal error from VM (only once, can't reproduce) and then this message from Eclipse (every time I start it): [Eclipse error](http://i47.tinypic.com/351g2tt.png)

Comment: what is the message because i don't have access to the attached link. did you checked that the path to the `javaw` is correct?

Comment: I don't think there is a lot of useful info anyway... BUT I found a way! It wasn't working because of `-Xmx1024m`. I changed it to `-Xmx768m` - now it's alright! No idea why though.

Comment: add this solution to your answer please and I will set it as accepted :)

Comment: because after setting the -XX:MaxPermSize you didn't have enough memory and thats why it works when you reduced the -Xmx(max heap size) to 768m.

Answer (score 0):

Your eclipse.ini should be:

-XX:MaxPermSize=256m